# generating EXTI0 interrupt when extenal temperature sensor is connected to STM32F207VC

Tags: sensors, stm32, adc

I am using STM32F207VC controller . I have my  external probe temperature sensor connected to one of the internal ADC channel of stm32.

I want to generate an  external interrupt when this is connected to controller and i should start measuring from external temperature sensor.

Please could any one provide me code or any help in this

Thanks

Comment: So, do you need help generating and external interrupt, reading from the ADC, or both?

Comment: Please help me  in genearting interrupt.

Answer (score 1):

I have an STM32F4 processor interfaced with a Solomon Systems SSD1963 GPU.  The GPU has a Tearing Signal (TE) that notifies the processor when it is about to do a vertical refresh.  I hope you can use this code as an example and adapt it to your solution.

The TE signal is connected to the CPU's GPIO G7 pin.  So first I have to configure the GPIO pin.

```
//GPIO Pin G7
GPIO_StructInit(&GPIO_InitStructure);
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_7;
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_IN;
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_100MHz;
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_NOPULL;
GPIO_Init(GPIOG, &GPIO_InitStructure);
```

Next  I have to configure the interrupt and NVIC.

```
SYSCFG_EXTILineConfig(EXTI_PortSourceGPIOG, EXTI_PinSource7);

EXTI_InitTypeDef EXTI_InitStructure;
EXTI_StructInit(&EXTI_InitStructure);
EXTI_InitStructure.EXTI_Line = EXTI_Line7;
EXTI_InitStructure.EXTI_Mode = EXTI_Mode_Interrupt;
EXTI_InitStructure.EXTI_Trigger = EXTI_Trigger_Rising;
EXTI_InitStructure.EXTI_LineCmd = ENABLE;
EXTI_Init(&EXTI_InitStructure);

NVIC_InitTypeDef NVIC_InitStructure;
NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannel = EXTI9_5_IRQn;
NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelPreemptionPriority = 0x01;
NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelSubPriority = 0x01;
NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelCmd = ENABLE;
NVIC_Init(&NVIC_InitStructure);
```

Finally I have to create the interrupt handler.  The `EXTI9_5_IRQHandler` handles external interrupts on lines 5 ~ 7.  This method is actually defined  in my CPUs startup assembly file as a weak reference.  I just need to redefine the method and the linker will do the rest.

```
extern "C" void EXTI9_5_IRQHandler(void)
{
    if(EXTI_GetITStatus(EXTI_Line7) != RESET)
    {
        //Handle the interrupt

        EXTI_ClearITPendingBit(EXTI_Line7);
    }
}
```

I'm using Mentor Graphics' Sourcery Codebench Lite as my toolchain.

Comment: Thanks Verax. I will have a look into it, and get back if i have any doubts

Comment: Hi Verax, your device is connected to some GPIO pin. But my sensor is connected to internal ADC channel. Is there any other good option other ADC scanning, so that i can generate interrupt??

Comment: I don't think you want to use an analog signal to generate an interrupt.  I think you should use a digital signal connected to a one of the the external interrupt GPIO pins like in my sample. Then your sensor would be connected separately to the ADC.  Then when you receive an interrupt from your digital signal, you would then read from the ADC.